# Java: Can instanceof also check "enclosing classes"?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

Is instanceof able to check also the enclosing class (not sure if that is the right wording for my problem)?

Please see below.

**Car.java**

```
public class Car
{
    public static class Wheel {}
}

class CarA extends Car {}

class CarB extends Car {}
```

**x.java**

```
public class x
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("*******");
        
        CarA.Wheel caw = new CarA.Wheel ();
        CarB.Wheel cbw = new CarB.Wheel ();
        System.out.println (caw instanceof CarA.Wheel);
        System.out.println (caw instanceof CarB.Wheel);
        System.out.println (cbw instanceof CarA.Wheel);
        System.out.println (cbw instanceof CarB.Wheel);
    }
}
```

** Output is **

```
true
true
true
true
```

But I am looking for

```
true
false
false 
true
```

I understand Wheel is always the same because of the extend but is there a way I can include CarA/CarB into the check (without implementiering Wheel in CarA and also in CarB)??

Comment: What do you gain from that? Maybe your design can be improved.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a better way, but I would add a constructor and then in both classes pass a value through indicating from which outer type it came from.

Comment: Ask yourself the right question. Do you need to know if a wheel belongs to a CarA or a CarB, or do you need to have different wheels for cars A and cars B? In the first case, you shouldn't check it with instanceof but some method of Wheel. In the second case, you should have two different classes. But only you know the business logic you want to implement here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have exactly one `Wheel` class. `Car.Wheel`, `CarA.Wheel` and `CarB.Wheel` are just different names for that same class, and that is why `instanceof` evaluates to true for all of those types.

An alternative way of doing this without (explicitly) introducing a new field in `Wheel` or having every `Car` have their own `Wheel` class is to make `Wheel` non-static. Now the wheel knows which car it came from.

```
public class Car
{
    public class Wheel {
        public Car getCar() {
            return Car.this;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Car.Wheel wheel = new CarA().new Wheel();
System.out.println(wheel.getCar() instanceof CarA); // true
System.out.println(wheel.getCar() instanceof CarB); // false
```

Under the hood though, by making it non-static, a synthetic field is implicitly added to `Wheel` to record which car it came from, so you might consider this "cheating".

Comment: Which also means that to create a Wheel instance, you must have a Car instance. `new CarA.Wheel()` is no longer possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, with `instanceof` it is not possible. As you mentioned, the `Wheel` class is exists only once. Just because you access it through a different path doesn't make it a different class.

Comment: Any other way to do it without having a double Wheel or having a member inside Wheel that tells me if it is A or B?

Comment: @chris01 `CarA.Wheel` and `CarB.Wheel` refer to exactly the same class. You can't differentiate between the 2 because there is nothing to differentiate, they are identical. There is absolutely no difference between them. Maybe if you could explain why you want to know how this class was created someone could point out a better way of doing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm under the impression you are looking at this from the wrong angle. Why do you need different _classes_? Why don't your car _objects_ (instances) reference a wheel _instance_? Something like `Car carA = new Car(new Wheel()); Car carB = new Car(new Wheel());` Why do you need separate types?

Comment: Or even have a car instance referencing four wheel instances…

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, functionally speaking, whether you need to have distinct wheels for each type of Car, or rather you need to know to which type of Car a specific wheel belongs to.

In the first case the answer is quick: you need to duplicate your class into `WheelA` and `WheelB`.

In the second case, you simply shouldn't use `instanceof` to check. You may do something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public static class Wheel<T extends Car> {

        private final Class<T> carType;

        public Wheel(Class<T> carType) {
            this.carType = carType;
        }

        public Class<T> getCarType() {
            return carType;
        }
    }
}
```

Hence your code would change like this:

```
public class x
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("*******");
        
        CarA.Wheel<CarA> caw = new CarA.Wheel<> (CarA.class);
        System.out.println (caw.getCarType().equals(CarA.class));
        System.out.println (caw.getCarType().equals(CarB.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly why I find inner classes not clear (sorry for opinion)

An "static inner class" (it's called like that) Is just a kind of class that is declared in another class, but it just react the same way as if it was declared outside of that class.

And since it's static, it work exactly as if you had String constant: they have the same value in the parent and in the child classes:
Car.Wheel.class == CarA.Wheel.class == CarB.Wheel.class

```
    System.out.println(CarA.Wheel.class == Car.Wheel.class);
    
    System.out.println(CarA.Wheel.class);
    System.out.println(CarB.Wheel.class);
```

prints

```
true
class local.Car$Wheel
class local.Car$Wheel
```

And since you cannot override anything that is static in java, there are no reason to refer to CarA.Wheel and CarB.Wheel

To me, and that's a specific Opinion, you don't really need to do an inner class in this case: Car and Wheel could be on same level in the package.

Inner classes that aren't static are another story.